# How can I pop an element from a Set in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, set

In Python I can do `a_set.pop()` and I remove an element from the set and catch it in a variable. Is there a way to do the same thing with a set in Ruby?

Comment: Can you please clarify? Are you talking about something like `pop` out a subarray within an array?

Comment: The terms "push" and "pop" come from the manipulation of elements in a stack. To pop an element from a stack means to remove the top-most item. "Popping an element from an array" is derived from that. Both assume an ordering of elements. Elements of sets are not ordered, so it makes no sense to "pop" an element from one. If you wish to remove a particular element from a set, you can use [Set#delete](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-delete) or [Set#delete?](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-delete-3F), depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to research a question like this is to look at the docs.  A Google search for 'ruby set' will help you to find the [doc for the ruby Set class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html).  You can then review all of the available instance methods.

As you can see, a Set is "a collection of unordered values with no duplicates." Since it's unordered, it's not designed to get values at particular locations within the set, including the last value.

You could convert to an array using `#to_a` and then use `#pop` on the array, but since the order of a Set is not guaranteed, you might not end up with the value you're expecting.

**Edit:**  Interestingly, `pop` in Python deletes and returns "an arbitrary element."  I see now that that's what you were looking for.  While this is not available as a built-in method in a Ruby set, I suppose you could implement it using `Array#sample`, which grabs a random element from an array, and then delete it from the Set:

```
class Set
  def pop
    el = self.to_a.sample
    self.delete(el)
    el
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand that, but in Python it's possible, and as I didn't find this in de docs, I just wanted to know if it was possible in Ruby. Thank you.

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean now.  `pop` for Python sets: "remove and return an arbitrary element..."  That's pretty strange, as the term `pop` is usually used to mean removing and returning the LAST element.

Comment: An"arbitrary" element is not necessarily an element selected at random.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby Set haven't `pop` method, but you can do like this:

```
class Set
  def pop
    temp = self.to_a.pop
    self.delete(temp)
    temp
  end
end

s1 = Set.new [1, 2]
=> #<Set: {1, 2}>
s1.pop
=> 2
s1
=> #<Set: {1}>
```

Answer (score 1):

`pop` should always mean popped off the stack. A stack is last-in-first-out. That to me would mean that

1) The set should be ordered
2) The last element added is the one that gets `popped`

My implementation would be:

```
class Set
  def pop
    element = to_a.last
    delete(element)
    element
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not just use a `SortedSet`?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want any element of the set returned, this will work.

```rb
class Set
  def pop
    popped = first
    delete(first)
    popped
  end
end
```